# I have a question while performing distributed training using Horovod (Gloo and MPI)

Tags: process, openmpi, distributed-training, horovod, gloo

I have a question while performing distributed training using Horovod. In the results from Gloo and MPI, I noticed that Gloo displays [0] [1] [2] [3] on the left during training, while MPI displays [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [1,3]. What does this mean? I thought the numbers in Gloo represent process numbers, but what is the relationship between all processes and process 1 in MPI? I am attaching the code I ran and the resulting.

My environment is as follows:
Ubuntu 20.04 Cluster : MN, hpc01, hpc03

This is code I ran (test.py)

```
    import argparse
    import os
    from packaging import version

    import torch.multiprocessing as mp
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    import torch.optim as optim
    import torch.utils.data.distributed
    from filelock import FileLock
    from torchvision import datasets, transforms

    import horovod
    import horovod.torch as hvd

    import time
    start_time = time.time()

    # Training settings
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch MNIST Example')   
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=64, metavar='N',
                        help='input batch size for training (default: 64)')
    parser.add_argument('--test-batch-size', type=int, default=1000, metavar='N',
                        help='input batch size for testing (default: 1000)')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=10, metavar='N',
                        help='number of epochs to train (default: 10)')
    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.01, metavar='LR',
                        help='learning rate (default: 0.01)')
    parser.add_argument('--momentum', type=float, default=0.5, metavar='M',
                        help='SGD momentum (default: 0.5)')
    parser.add_argument('--no-cuda', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='disables CUDA training')
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=42, metavar='S',
                        help='random seed (default: 42)')
    parser.add_argument('--log-interval', type=int, default=10, metavar='N',
                        help='how many batches to wait before logging training status')
    parser.add_argument('--fp16-allreduce', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='use fp16 compression during allreduce')
    parser.add_argument('--use-mixed-precision', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='use mixed precision for training')
    parser.add_argument('--use-adasum', action='store_true', default=False,
                        help='use adasum algorithm to do reduction')
    parser.add_argument('--gradient-predivide-factor', type=float, default=1.0,
                        help='apply gradient predivide factor in optimizer (default: 1.0)')
    parser.a dd_argument('--data-dir',
                        help='location of the training dataset in the local filesystem (will be          downloaded if needed)')

    # Arguments when not run through horovodrun
    parser.add_argument('--num-proc', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--hosts', help='hosts to run on in notation:        hostname:slots[,host2:slots[,...]]')
    parser.add_argument('--communication', help='collaborative communication to use: gloo, mpi')

    # Model 정의
    class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Net, self).__init__()
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
            self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 50)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

        def forward(self, x):
            x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 2))
            x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 2))
            x = x.view(-1, 320)
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
            x = self.fc2(x)
            return F.log_softmax(x)


def main(args):
    # 분산 환경에서 모델 학습
    def train_epoch(epoch):
        model.train() # 모델을 학습 모드로 설정
        # Horovod: set epoch to sampler for shuffling.
        # 데이터셋을 셔플링 -> 데이터의 순서를 섞는것. 
    
        train_sampler.set_epoch(epoch)
        # 배치 단위로 데이터를 가져옴
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
            # gradient를 0으로 초기화
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # 데이터를 모델에 입력하여 예측값 output을 얻음
            output = model(data)
            # 예측 값 output과 실제 값 target 사이의 loss 계산
            loss = F.nll_loss(output, target)
            loss.backward() # backpropagation
            optimizer.step() # 파라미터 업데이트
            if batch_idx % args.log_interval == 0:
                # Horovod: use train_sampler to determine the number of examples in
                # this worker's partition.
                print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                    epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_sampler),
                           100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))

    # Metric: accuracy, loss -> 각 워커에서 계산된 값을 모아서 평균을 계산하는 함수
    def metric_average(val, name):
        tensor = torch.tensor(val)
        # allreduce 방식으로 계산
        avg_tensor = hvd.allreduce(tensor, name=name)
        return avg_tensor.item()

    def test():
        model.eval() # 모델을 평가 모드로
        test_loss = 0.
        test_accuracy = 0.
        # 테스트 데이터셋에서 배치 단위로 data와 target을 가져옴
        for data, target in test_loader:
            # 모델에 데이터 입력 -> 예측 결과를 얻음 
            output = model(data)
            # sum up batch loss
            # batch 마다 loss 누적
            test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, size_average=False).item()
            # get the index of the max log-probability
            # 예측된 label을 얻음
            pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
            # batch 마다 accuracy 누적
            test_accuracy += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).cpu().float().sum()

        # Horovod: use test_sampler to determine the number of examples in
        # this worker's partition.
        # 평균 loss and accuracy
        test_loss /= len(test_sampler)
        test_accuracy /= len(test_sampler)

        # Horovod: average metric values across workers.
        # 각 워커에서 계산된 metric(loss, accuracy)를 전체 워커들 간에 평균화
        test_loss = metric_average(test_loss, 'avg_loss')
        test_accuracy = metric_average(test_accuracy, 'avg_accuracy')

        # Horovod: print output only on first rank.
        if hvd.rank() == 0:
            print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.2f}%\n'.format(
                test_loss, 100. * test_accuracy))

    # Horovod: initialize library.
    hvd.init()
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)

    # Horovod: limit # of CPU threads to be used per worker.
    # 각 작업별로 CPU thread 1개 사용
    torch.set_num_threads(1)

    kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True} if args.cuda else {}
   
    if (kwargs.get('num_workers', 0) > 0 and hasattr(mp, '_supports_context') and
            mp._supports_context and 'forkserver' in mp.get_all_start_methods()):
        kwargs['multiprocessing_context'] = 'forkserver'

   
    data_dir = args.data_dir or './data'
  
    with FileLock(os.path.expanduser("~/.horovod_lock")):
        train_dataset = \
            datasets.MNIST(data_dir, train=True, download=True,
                           transform=transforms.Compose([
                               transforms.ToTensor(),
                               transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                           ]))

   

    train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
        train_dataset, num_replicas=hvd.size(), rank=hvd.rank())
    
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, sampler=train_sampler, **kwargs)

    test_dataset = \
        datasets.MNIST(data_dir, train=False, transform=transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
        ]))
    
    test_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
        test_dataset, num_replicas=hvd.size(), rank=hvd.rank())
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=args.test_batch_size,
                                              sampler=test_sampler, **kwargs)

    model = Net()

    # By default, Adasum doesn't need scaling up learning rate.
    lr_scaler = hvd.size() if not args.use_adasum else 1

    # Horovod: scale learning rate by lr_scaler.
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr * lr_scaler,
                          momentum=args.momentum)

    # Horovod: broadcast parameters & optimizer state.
    
    hvd.broadcast_parameters(model.state_dict(), root_rank=0)

    hvd.broadcast_optimizer_state(optimizer, root_rank=0)


    # Horovod: wrap optimizer with DistributedOptimizer.
    
    optimizer = hvd.DistributedOptimizer(optimizer,
                                         named_parameters=model.named_parameters(),
                                         op=hvd.Adasum if args.use_adasum else hvd.Average,
                                         gradient_predivide_factor=args.gradient_predivide_factor)

  
    for epoch in range(1, args.epochs + 1):
        train_epoch(epoch)
        # Keep test in full precision since computation is relatively light.
        test()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        args = parser.parse_args()
        args.cuda = not args.no_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available()  
 
        # this is running via horovodrun
        main(args)

        if hvd.rank() == 0:
            end_time = time.time()
            print("총 소요 시간: %.3f초" %(end_time - start_time))
```

This is hovorodrun code (MN)

`hovorodrun -np 4 --mpi(or gloo) -H hpc01:2,hpc03:2 python3 test.py`

This is result of gloo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgQgl.png)

This is result of mpi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyEBu.png)

What does the digit "1" connected to all the numbers on the left side of the MPI result signify?

Thank you.